# Terraform distinct value

Tags: terraform

I have this variable in terraform :

```
domain_lst = {
  env1 = { dns = "application1.domain.com" }
  env2 = { dns = "application2.domain.com" }
  env3 = { dns = "application1.domain.com" }
}
```

I'd like to extract a list of distinct values :

```
["application1.domain.com","application2.domain.com"]
```

How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
> distinct(values(local.domain_lst)[*].dns)
tolist([
  "application1.domain.com",
  "application2.domain.com",
])
```